# GCP: Unable to create Project Sink through gcloud/API

Tags: service-accounts, google-iam, google-cloud-logging, google-deployment-manager

I currently have a scenario wherein I created deployment script (python) using the Deployment Manager, it runs perfectly well in a GCP sandbox (LA Playground) I tend to use to try things out. But when I tried running it on an actual GCP project with billing accounts etc., I get a permission error even though I'm using basically the same set of roles in the service account I created for it. I also am the project owner of that troubling GCP account.

The particular set of permission I'm having problems with is in creating project sinks. I always get the following error:

```
Error in Operation [operation-xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-9d487530]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/structured-pipeline/resources/dataprep-bq-listener-sink
  message: '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/logging-v2:projects.sinks","ResourceErrorCode":"403","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":403,"message":"The
    caller does not have permission","status":"PERMISSION_DENIED","statusMessage":"Forbidden","requestPath":"https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/redacted-gcp-project-name-dev/sinks","httpMethod":"POST"}}'
```

Here's the list of roles I have attached on the service account that is used to run the deployment:

- Compute Admin
- Deployment Manager Editor
- Security Admin
- Logging Admin
- Logs Configuration Writer
- Pub/Sub Admin
- Service Usage Admin
- Storage Admin

As you may see, I already made them admin level just to make sure I'm not missing a required permission.

As per the official documentation, the specific permission needed for creating projects sinks is `logging.sinks.create` which is included in both `Logging Admin` & `Logs Configuration Writer` roles.

**UPDATE#1:**

Here's the expanded DM config of the troubled resources

```
- name: dataprep-bq-listener-sink
  properties:
    destination: pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/redacted-gcp-project-name-dev/topics/dataprep-bq-listener-vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh
    filter: |-
      resource.type="bigquery_dataset"
      resource.labels.dataset_id="dataprep_output_vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh"
      protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"
    outputVersionFormat: V2
    sink: dataprep-bq-listener-sink-vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh
  type: gcp-types/logging-v2:projects.sinks
- accessControl:
    gcpIamPolicy:
      bindings:
      - members:
        - $(ref.dataprep-bq-listener-sink.writerIdentity)
        role: roles/pubsub.publisher
  name: dataprep-bq-listener
  properties:
    labels:
      client_namespace: redacted-client-name
    topic: dataprep-bq-listener-vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh
  type: pubsub.v1.topic
  metadata:
    dependsOn:
    - dataprep-bq-listener-sink
```

**UPDATE#2**

I set my `gcloud` to use a service account for credentials (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account) which has the roles I stated above.

Running `gcloud auth list` clearly points to the service account I created/used.

```
ACTIVE  ACCOUNT
        my_redacted_email@company.com
        cloud_user_p_2725ef46@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_2e3db20d@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_41b5121a@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_b57aaef8@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_bdb72060@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_c2f5d19a@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_c3c54122@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_c88350f1@linuxacademygclabs.com
        cloud_user_p_d7702b8b@linuxacademygclabs.com
*       service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com

To set the active account, run:
    $ gcloud config set account `ACCOUNT`
```

**UPDATE#3**

Running `gcloud projects get-iam-policy <PROJECT_ID>` results to the following list of IAM policies *(I've replaced my email with "**my_redacted_email@company.com**" and the service account email I used for the DM with "**service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com**"; all the default default service accounts I retained)*

```
bindings:
- members:
  - user: my_redacted_email@company.com
  role: roles/billing.projectManager
- members:
  - serviceAccount:1008104628570@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudbuild.builds.builder
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@gcp-sa-cloudbuild.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudbuild.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudfunctions.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/cloudscheduler.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@compute-system.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/compute.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@containerregistry.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/containerregistry.ServiceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@dataflow-service-producer-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/dataflow.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service-1008104628570@trifacta-gcloud-prod.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/dataprep.serviceAgent
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/deploymentmanager.editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:1008104628570-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:1008104628570@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  - user:my_redacted_email@company.com
  role: roles/editor
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/iam.securityAdmin
- members:
  - user:my_redacted_email@company.com
  role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/logging.admin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/logging.configWriter
- members:
  - user:my_redacted_email@company.com
  role: roles/owner
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/pubsub.admin
- members:
  - user:my_redacted_email@company.com
  role: roles/resourcemanager.projectIamAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageAdmin
- members:
  - serviceAccount:service_account_used_in_dm@project_id.iam.gserviceaccount.com
  role: roles/storage.admin
etag: BwW0MM3sGXk=
version: 1
```

As you may noticed the service account I'm using has bindings to the roles that I mentioned above at the project level.

**UPDATE#4**

Creating the sink through `gcloud` using the same service account results in a successful creation of the sink.

```
gcloud logging sinks create dataprep-bq-listener-sink-vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh pubsub.googleapis.com/projects/<project_id>/topics/dataprep-bq-listener-vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh --log-filter='resource.type="bigquery_dataset" AND resource.labels.dataset_id="dataprep_output_vpcps3s6wjzbmkbxxlsqqh" AND protoPayload.methodName="google.cloud.bigquery.v2.JobService.InsertJob"' --project=<project_id>
```

**UPDATE#5**

@Kolban did note of the requirement of Deployment Manager for the `[PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` service account to the `Editor` role as [per stated in their official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/access-control#access_control_for), now looking at **UPDATE#4**, it clearly shows that the said service account has the `Editor` role.

He also noted for possible mixing up of multiple cloud accounts (I might be running the command using the service account but under a different cloud account), thus, I executed the following commands: `gcloud config get-value account` & `gcloud config get-value project` which resulted to what I'm expecting which is the correct GCP project and Service Account pair.

Comment: What is the destination of the GCP Cloud Logging sink that you are trying to define?

Comment: Hello @Kolban, the destination of the sink is to a pubsub topic

Comment: What is the exact command you are running to define the Cloud Logging sink?  What GCP identity do you believe is running the command?

Comment: Hello @Kolban, I run the deployment script via python (following -> https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/at-scale) I have updated my post to contain the DM expanded config of the troubled resources. 

In regards to the identity, at first I just used the default credentials (`gcloud auth login`) using my email, but then I thought my email permissions might not be enough so I did use service account next (https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/authorizing#authorizing_with_a_service_account) and this is the one I said I basically am using the same set of credentials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [docs](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/access-control#access_control_for) state:-

> To create other Google Cloud resources, Deployment Manager uses the
> credentials of the Google APIs service account to authenticate to
> other APIs. The Google APIs service account is designed specifically
> to run internal Google processes on your behalf. The service account
> is identifiable using the email:
>
> [PROJECT_NUMBER]@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com

In your case, your `1008104628570@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` Service Account is bound to the `roles\editor` role at project level. However, the permission you require (`logging.sinks.create`) isn't contained within that legacy Editor role.

Can you try additionally granting the `1008104628570@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` Service Account the Logging Admin role (`roles/logging.admin`) and see if that helps?

Comment: Hello @Philip Wigg, thanks ! that actually did the trick. It's confusing for the documentation to state that "it is not recommended that you modify this account's permissions" and then later find out, you actually have to modify it to allow DM to perform other tasks.